# Where is the list of supported CPU profiles in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, cpu

I thought I found a list of CPU profiles for VirtualBox. I just can't find it again.

I can see my current Host CPU information with the following command:

```
vboxmanage list hostcpuids
```

but I wanted to test various profiles with one of my VMs which is not currently booting. Something like this:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "myVM" --cpu-profile "Intel Core i7–6700K"
```

Only if the profile doesn't exist, the VM will fail (it won't start at all). So I'm wondering how can I find a list of CPU profiles that will work on my host system?

Update:

From `/proc/cpuinfo` (one entry of 64):

```
processor   : 63
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 85
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4216 CPU @ 2.10GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x500002c
cpu MHz     : 800.882
cache size  : 22528 KB
physical id : 1
siblings    : 32
core id     : 15
cpu cores   : 16
apicid      : 63
initial apicid  : 63
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single intel_ppin ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cqm mpx rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts pku ospke avx512_vnni md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs taa itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 4201.65
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: I thought it will work for all CPUs of the same architecture, even if it has to fall back to emulation mode.

Comment: What is the host CPU and what is the Guest OS? As far as I can tell, Virtualbox can modify the CPU but only "backwards". You cannot emulate instruction sets that your processor doesn't even support.

Comment: @kemotep I added my cpuinfo output (one entry). I'm also reading that [VirtualBox version 6.0.x](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-6.0) probably has the support I'm looking for (a.k.a. more macOS specific settings). So that might be enough. It may also support AVX512 which right now do no appear in my VMs...

Comment: Are you looking for `VBoxManage list cpu-profiles`?

Comment: It looks like that option is new (VB 7+?). On my system, which still has version 6.1, it gives me an error when I try with `cpu-profiles`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some research myself and found something in their .dll (on a Windows host).

In the `.rdata` section of `Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxVMM.dll` you can find some types which might work (I did not test all of them). I reformatted it a little to make it more readable:

```
AMD Athlon 64 3200+
AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4200+  AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core 4200+
 Quad-Core AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 2384
 Quad-Core AMD Opteron 2384
 AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1100T Processor    AMD Phenom II X6 1100T  AMD FX(tm)-8150 Eight-Core Processor    AMD FX-8150 Eight-Core  Intel(R) 8086   Intel 8086
 Intel(R) 80186  Intel 80186
Intel(R) 80286  Intel 80286
Intel(R) 80386  Intel 80386
Intel(R) 80486DX2
Intel 80486
Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU  330   @ 1.60GHz  Intel Atom 330 1.60GHz  Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU  N3530  @ 2.16GHz
Intel Pentium N3530 2.16GHz
Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 3.00GHz
Intel Pentium 4 3.00GHz Intel(R) Pentium(R) M processor 2.00GHz Intel Pentium M processor 2.00GHz
Genuine Intel(R) CPU
    T2600  @ 2.16GHz Intel Core Duo T2600 2.16GHz    Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU
  T7600  @ 2.33GHz Intel Core2 T7600 2.33GHz
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU
  X6800  @ 2.93GHz Intel Core2 X6800 2.93GHz
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU
    X5482  @ 3.20GHz Intel Xeon X5482 3.20GHz
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2635QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
Intel Core i7-2635QM    Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570 CPU @ 3.40GHz Intel Core i5-3570
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3960X CPU @ 3.30GHz
 Intel Core i7-3960X
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
 Intel Core i7-5600U
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700K CPU @ 4.00GHz
 Intel Core i7-6700K
```

Comment: Oh so it may be compiled instead of an editable file. That could make sense to avoid you to try to use a setup which would not be compatible with the VBox code. I wonder whether there would be a command line option that lists those, then.

Comment: Seems like that. I also cannot understand why there is no official list for that.