# VirtualBox Win 7 Update Failed with Processor not Supported

Tags: virtualbox, cpu, software-updates

It's a freshly created win 7 pro 32-bit vm on a VirtualBox. However the windows update only worked before the latest two. It gets ["the **processor is not supported** together with the Windows version that you are currently using" error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4012982/the-processor-is-not-supported-together-with-the-windows-version-that). The host OS is Ubuntu 18.04, process is i7 7700HQ.

On another host it updated to the latest KB3042058, following a KB4534310, and a KB4536952. On the problematic vm, it gets stuck at KB4536952 with the error.

One of two solutions suggested by a virtualbox forum topic is to [change inside a windows system file](https://github.com/zeffy/kb4012218-19) as discussed on the virtualbox box forum "[Concern: Microsoft block win7/8.1 update with new CPU](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=82299)". The another of the two is to run these two commands:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm "virtual machine name" --cpuid-portability-level 1
vboxmanage modifyvm "virtual machine name" --cpuidset 80000004 372e3220 7a484730 00000000 00000000
```

I did run the two commands, the guest win 7 still reports the same system processor "i7 7700HQ" as it used to, and the update still fails the same as before.

Another post on this SE site suggests to [use only a valid cpu profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557724/where-is-the-list-of-supported-cpu-profiles-in-virtualbox). A list can be found on a [virtualbox forum topic "specifying the processor type the vm sees](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=84423). The two commands are changed to:

```
vboxmanage modifyvm "virtual machine name" --cpuid-portability-level 1
vboxmanage modifyvm "virtual machine name" --cpu-profile "Intel Core i5-3570"
```

Again it is not working. I also tried to change `"Intel Core i5-3570"` to `"Intel Core i7-2635QM"`. In both cases, the guest OS will see the different processor types as set by the command, but the update still fails the same as before.

Any idea how to fix this?

Another data point is that on both the two win 7 vm's when it is initially created, it [fails windows update](https://superuser.com/questions/1131583/windows-update-not-working-in-virtualbox) for a few times. On one of them it updated overnight when left alone. Then I clicked through multiple updates till the latest is done. On the second I just clicked to check for updates it worked for a bunch of successful updates till it fails. Not sure why these two are so different.

Comment: Have you tried changing setting up in VirtualBox the VM configuration with the setting "Windows 10"?

Comment: Rui, Thanks for suggesting. The VM was from an IE testing .ova by microsoft, imported. It did not give an option to check "Windows 10" but it should have been implicitly check in the .ova image, I assume. Other than that, I did turned all other acceleration options under the sysetm processor tab in settings.

Comment: Another difference is that on the second system all updates are manually initialed by clicking "check for updates". At one point, it was failing with error code 80092004. Based on a [page on gohacks.net](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/08/15/if-you-get-windows-update-error-0x80092004-on-windows-7-or-server-2008-r2-do-this/), I manually downloaded and installed KB4490628. When tried another suggested KB4474419, it prompts not applicable. The page says the reason is that the sha-2-only signing change does not get installed when updating manually.

Comment: For the failing-first-few-updates problem, I figured just to wait for about 20 minutes till it runs at 100% cpu load for a while. Guessing something needs to be set up in background by windows before it could perform update properly. Though also turned automatic update on and off a few times, that may affect.

Comment: U&L is not much concerned with the Windows side of problems, I am afraid. superuser might be a better match on those cases, though they are more sysadmin oriented (if memory does not fail me)

Comment: Rui, The solution is on the host Linux side, not the guest Windows side.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been solved by performing actions in this order:

- Import the vm.
- Set CPU profile to `"Intel Core i5-3570"`.
- Update the guest.

I'm guessing at some point in update, the guest remembers the CPU model permanantly.